# IntentService doesn't work with resultreceiver

Tags: android, intentservice, android-geofence, custom-receiver

I'm having trouble passing an object back after the intentservice is completed. 
My goal is to send the currentCharacter object back to the Mainactivity after the notification has been sent. I tried it with an onResult but the intentservice doesn't have this. I also tried creating an own resultreceiver but when I implement this, the notification doesn't even come through. Does anyone know a solution or a work around for this problem?

This is the GeofenceTransitionIntentService that gets called from the MainActivity when I enter a specific region. I have a currentCharacter object which I want to send back to the MainActivity, where I also have a currentCharacter but this needs to be updated.

```
public class GeofenceTransitionIntentService extends IntentService {
protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private boolean checkedIn = false;
private List<Store> stores;
private Store rightStore;
private Character currentCharacter;
private ResultReceiver rec;

/**
 * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
 * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
 */
public GeofenceTransitionIntentService() {
    // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: geofencetransition");
}

/**
 * Handles incoming intents.
 *
 * @param intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided to Location
 *               Services (inside a PendingIntent) when addGeofences() is called.
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = "err";
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    if(!checkedIn) {
        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );

            stores = new Gson().fromJson(intent.getStringExtra("stores"),
                    new TypeToken<ArrayList<Store>>() {
                    }.getType());

            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            currentCharacter = new Gson().fromJson(intent.getStringExtra("char"),
                    Character.class);
            rec = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiverTag");
            String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            Checkin checkin = new Checkin(rightStore, date, 10);
            currentCharacter.getCheckins().add(checkin);
            currentCharacter.setCurrentExp(currentCharacter.getCurrentExp() + checkin.getReceivedExp());
            putCharacter();

            Log.d(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.d(TAG, "error");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Gets transition details and returns them as a formatted string.
 *
 * @param geofenceTransition  The ID of the geofence transition.
 * @param triggeringGeofences The geofence(s) triggered.
 * @return The transition details formatted as String.
 */
private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
        int geofenceTransition,
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

    String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

    // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
    ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
        triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
    }
    String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

    return geofenceTransitionString + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
}

/**
 * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
 * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
 */
private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
    Intent notifyIntent;
    notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  StoresDetail.class);
    for(Store store : stores){
        if(notificationDetails.contains(store.getName())){
            rightStore = store;
        }
    }

    notifyIntent.putExtra("store", rightStore);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(getApplicationContext(), 1234,
            new Intent[] { notifyIntent }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
            .setContentText("Gamification")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(5678, notification);
}

/**
 * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
 *
 * @param transitionType A transition type constant defined in Geofence
 * @return A String indicating the type of transition
 */
private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
    switch (transitionType) {
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
            checkedIn = true;
            return "Entered geofence: ";
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
            checkedIn = false;
            return "Exited geofence: ";
        default:
            return "default";
    }
}

private void putCharacter(){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    APIService caller = new APIService();
    caller.put(queue, "character/", gson.toJson(currentCharacter), new VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            Log.d("GeofenceTransitionSer", "onSuccess of VolleyCallback, Method: putCharacter");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(String result) {
            Log.d("GeofenceTransitionSer", "onFailed of VolleyCallback, Method: putCharacter");

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Going through your code, you do have retrieved *ResultReceiver* by getParcelableExtra() but I do not see you sending a broadcast through it anywhere using `rec.send(int,Bundle);`

MainActivity will never get notified.
That is why the notification might not be coming through as you have said.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to understand the difference between a Service and an IntentService. Every time an IntentService is started, it’ll handle each Intent in turn by using a worker thread. That’s the main difference from the Service which is basically running on the main thread. That being said you have to find a way to send the status of the work request to the activity component. To do so, you can send a broadcast which will contain the currentCharacter to a BroadcastReceiver which should be existed in the Activity. Please have a look on the following link from the official android developers’ documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example of how this works exactly?
I looked in the docs but I can't figure it out ( the BroadcastReceiver)